# Pointing an 'object variable' with 'string value' and dynamically update it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to achieve a dynamic variable out of string value. The dynamic variable is the nested object. I used eval method of Javascript for that purpose. It worked as I expected.

To be more precise, here is the example:

```
var transport = [];
transport.vehicles[0].car.brake[2] = ['diskbrake','drumbrake']; 
var myString = "transport.vehicles[0].car.brake[2]"; 
var valueOfArray = eval(myString); 
console.log(valueOfArray);
```

Here, the console log gives me the desired output. But, I need to achieve something like dynamic update of 'transport' variable when I add new item to the "valueOfArray" variable.

```
valueOfArray.push('air brakes');
```

When I push the new value, it should also update 'transport' object.

Any guidance or suggestions would be very appreciable.

Thank you.

Comment: First, JS does not have associative arrays. Arrays are objects and hence you can play with it but its better to use Objects instead of arrays in such cases. Second, `eval` is bad practice. Search *eval is evil* for more info

Comment: If `transport.vehicles[0].car.brake[2]` refers to an array, your `valueOfArray` variable refers to that *same* array instance (not a copy of it), so if you use `valueOfArray.push()` you've added an item to `transport.vehicles[0].car.brake[2]`.

Comment: what are you doing?my god!!!

Comment: Also you cannot do something like `var a = []; a[2].object.property.value`. You will have to define these intermediate values before using them

Comment: Also if your Object is defined properly, and you can change the format of string, I'd suggest using bracket notation(`var path = "vehicles[0][car][brake[2]"]`) and then just accessing it like `transport[path] = ...`

Comment: Well what I am trying to do it, I have 'path' which goes to the nested object deep value. I am just trying to manipulate the value and pushed it back to the array. For now, I can have dynamic path to the nested value of object. What is the good way to do that, then?

Comment: @holi-java: Is it a bad practice?

Comment: @NirajPaudel why did you access data in such deep?that like drive a train...

Comment: @NirajPaudel In my opinion，you may need organize your data with OO ways. if you just use a path to retrieve the data,you know the data structure and the path,why didn't you access directly like `transport.vehicles[0].car.brake[2]`? this is easy and simple and error diagnosed.actually,resolve so deep path & retrieve data should be the work of  the `template`  engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lodash [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get), [set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#set). NPM module [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.set).
If you want to know how it is doing what it is doing in pure javascript, take a look at source code. Source code for [get](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/get.js), [set](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/set.js).

Example:

```
let object1 = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
 _.get(object1, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3

_.get(object1, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3

_.get(object1, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default'


let object2 = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.set(object2, 'a[0].b.c', 4);
console.log(object2.a[0].b.c);
// => 4

_.set(object2, ['x', '0', 'y', 'z'], 5);
console.log(object.x[0].y.z);
// => 5
```

So if you want to dynamically get and set an array, you can do it like this.

```
let object = {};
let array = _.get(object, 'transport.vehicles[0].car.brake[2]', []);
array.push('air brakes');
_.set(object, 'transport.vehicles[0].car.brake[2]', array);
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akLbj26z/)

Comment: Answer based on a library not tagged in question can get you downvotes.

Comment: Just trying to help out. He can take a look at source code instead, if he wants. I do not care much about my points, so you may as well downvote if you want. And probably he may not even know about the library, and if he already does, he would not have asked the question in first place. So, it will be wrong to expect him to add library tag.

Comment: Mate my comment was just a caveat. Your answer might be right, but adding a library to handle this case is wrong as the initial approach is wrong. It would help more if you also tell what is the right way to structure data and how to access them using paths in string. We all have partial knowledge and decide approach based on this partial approach and one wrong decision can make you do a lot of patch work.